# passing input type month with default day

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Is it possible to pass only a month and year in a form to Django :

```
 <input name="year_month_field" type="month" required>
```

with the day set to the first of the month by default?

It doesn't appear Django will accept a input type month from the form.

Current view code:

```
@login_required
def report_create_view(request, msgid=None):
    if msgid:
        msg = get_object_or_404(Message, pk=msgid)
    else:
        return redirect('report-list')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReportForm()
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.created_by = request.user
            obj.save()
            return redirect('report-list')
    else:
        form = ReportForm()

    return render(request, 'report_form.html', {
        'form': form,
        'msg': msg,
    })
```

Comment: It is possible, but to tell you how you need to post your current view that is mapping to this form.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, I've added my view.

Comment: Post your form and your model as well.